# Teamviewer installation failed

Tags: software-installation

I have download teamviewer.deb and click on it . It opened in Ubuntu Software center. And it shows the error

```
cant install libc6:i386
```

so i found this below command and i tried it on terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-amd64 libc6
```

but it shows some error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libc6-amd64:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6) but it is not            going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

this is the output of `apt-cache policy libc6:i386'

```
 libc6:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6
  Version table:
 2.19-0ubuntu6 0
    500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

Here is the screenshot of exact one.

[image]

Comment: what is output of `apt-cache policy libc6:i386`

Comment: this is the output `No command 'apt-cahe' found, did you mean:
 Command 'apt-cache' from package 'apt' (main)
apt-cahe: command not found
`

Comment: your command typo man :)

Comment: @Kvvaradha you mistyped it - it's C A C H E

Comment: sorry , now i typed it again, but it shows like this  `N: Unable to locate package libc`

Comment: Please copy paste, its `libc6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update #updates packages
sudo apt-get install -f #installs any missing packages if any
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-base:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386
```

Comment: still the same error . mine is 64 bit. while downloading debian. i see both 32 and 64 will work.

Comment: @Kvvaradha Please run: `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386` and try instaling again :)

Comment: still i am seeing the same errors. do i need to restart and try again  ?

Comment: Can you add exact output of `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`

Comment: I can see it  . but mine doesnot look like this. see it, i have edited the question

Comment: i cant see the reply option in chat

Comment: thanks it solved me , i just  followed your steps after restart